# How to apply shaders to canvas (javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas, shader

I have **no** experience with shaders at all. Not in javascript neither in any other language. I have seen shaders in JS with ThreeJS.

I would like to use shaders to manipulate parts of canvas for audio visualization, using bass filter and shaders. I did manage to get data from bass filter, but haven't got any clue how nor where to find good tutorials with shaders in vanilla JS, or some light weight framework.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a good answer :

> You draw your shape, then the shader1 (inner [bright, alplha(0.7)]), then shader2 (outer [not so bright, alpha(0.3)]).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasId").getContext("2d");

function drawSquare(X, Y, WaH, color) {
     ctx.beginPath();         //Draw suare
     ctx.fillStyle = color;
     ctx.fillRect(X, Y, WaH, WaH);
  
     ctx.beginPath();         //Draw shader 2
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)";
     ctx.arc(X + 20, Y + 20, 12.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
     ctx.fill();
  
     ctx.beginPath();         //Draw shader 1
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7)";
     ctx.arc(X + 20, Y + 20, 7.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
     ctx.fill();
}

drawSquare(50, 50, 100, "red");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

THIS ISN'T THE BEST, I DID **MY** BEST, OK???????